# Android (Yuphoria) stuck in bootloop without recovery and ROM & files cannot be written

Tags: custom-roms, boot-loop, micromax-yu-yuphoria

My **Yuphoria 5010** got into bootloop after installing a custom ROM. My friend tried to fix it but deleted the recovery following a tutorial.

Now the device is stuck at the boot logo.

Is it possible to hard format the device to the default ROM anyhow?

**Update:** This is not a normal bootloop. The problem here is the ROM could not be rewritten. Any writing attempts are being failed. The device was infected with a malicious adware which couldn't be deleted and that's the reason I tried to format the device. Is there any way around if the writing modules fail?

Comment: If you flashed a custom ROM, that *overwrote* (replaced) your "default ROM". So getting it back would mean to flash it. Same goes for the recovery, it can be flashed (provided you've got the image). Usually that's done via [fastboot](/tags/fastboot/info), but you might need to check if your device does that as well (not all devices support fastboot).

Comment: Is fastboot working?

Comment: @GokulNC fastboot is working but the problem is ROM is not being flashed as all writing attempts are failing

Comment: To get more specific help, you'll need to explain more precisely than "failing". What commands did you run, and what results did you get? Give the exact text of any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Flashing a stock firmware should fix this.

- Download and extract [Yu Yuphoria YU5010 stock firmware](http://www.mediafire.com/file/sasqefkme2jeqn0/Yu_Yuphoria_YU5010_V2_V2_12.10.12.zip) on your computer
- After extracting, you should get the **Firmware File,** **Flash Tool**  and **How-to Flash Guide**.
- Install the [USB Driver](https://androidmtk.com/download-yu-usb-driver) on your Computer
- Follow the How-to Flash Guide to Flash the Firmware .

Follow the steps carefully and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Nothing could be written

Comment: What do you mean?